# how to combine multiple dictionaries from list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this one:

```
 my_dict =  [{'year-0': '2022', 'dividend-0': ''},
 {'year-1': '2021', 'dividend-1': '52.37'},
 {'year-2': '2020', 'dividend-2': '44.57'},
 {'year-3': '2019', 'dividend-3': '35.00'},
 {'year-4': '2018', 'dividend-4': '24.00'},
 {'year-5': '2017', 'dividend-5': '23.94'}]
```

How I can combine these dictionaries into one dictionary like that ?:

```
{'year-0': '2022',
 'dividend-0': '',
 'year-1': '2021',
 'dividend-1': '52.37',
 'year-2': '2020',
 'dividend-2': '44.57',
 'year-3': '2019',
 'dividend-3': '35.00',
 'year-4': '2018',
 'dividend-4': '24.00',
 'year-5': '2017',
 'dividend-5': '23.94'}
```

I can do it using a simple loop, but maybe there is a more elegant way ?

```
x=dict()
for d in my_dict:
    x.update(d)
```

Comment: This may produce subjective answers.

Comment: You could use `reduce()`, but your loop is fine.

Comment: Neither the original list nor the result seems particularly useful. Wouldn't it be better to have a dictionary like `{2022: '', 2021: '52.37', ...}`? And why is everything a string instead of numbers?

Comment: If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you'll get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```
new_dict ={x:y for d in my_dict for x,y in d.items()}
```

Which gives your wanted result from your data.

Comment: The solution is slower in execution compared with the orignal proposal (see my posted investigation) and less good readable from my point of view

Answer (score 0):

The output data structure can probably be optimized into a dictionary of strings or a dictionary of numbers, like so:

```
dct1 = {tuple(item.values())[0] : tuple(item.values())[1] for item in my_dict}
print(dct1)
# {'2022': '', '2021': '52.37', '2020': '44.57', '2019': '35.00', '2018': '24.00', '2017': '23.94'}

dct2 = {}
for item in my_dict:
    vals = tuple(item.values())
    k = int(vals[0])
    try:
        v = float(vals[1])
    except:
        v = None
    dct2[k] = v

print(dct2)
# {2022: None, 2021: 52.37, 2020: 44.57, 2019: 35.0, 2018: 24.0, 2017: 23.94}
```

Although this is not exactly what you asked for, this data structure may be better in that it is not as repetitive. Note that the first example uses [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), and the second example uses a simple loop for readability.

Answer (score 0):

A short investigation delivers (on my PC, Python 3.9):

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: {x:y for d in my_dict for x,y in d.items()}, number=100) 
0.00012549999519251287

>>> def build(my_dict):
...     x=dict()
...     for i in my_dict:
...         x.update(i)
...     return x
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: build(my_dict), number=100)
7.940000796224922e-05

>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: functools.reduce(lambda i,ii: i.update(ii) or i ,my_dict), number=100)
6.53000024612993e-05
```

The conclusion for my setup is that the double comprehension is not the better solution. Original code is quicker and better readable.  `functools.reduce()` as already proposed by Barma is the quickest solution but here it modifies original list/dicts.